# iOS MKMapView - stop map view from re-centering to the user's location if the user has panned/dragged the map view

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, core-location

I have an `MKMapView` in which I have set:

```
[self.mapView setShowsUserLocation:YES];
```

I want to show the user's location, and update the location if he/she moves. When `didUpdateUserLocation` gets called it seems like the map re-centers to the user's location, even if the user have panned the app to see another region. What I want is to be able to track the user's position, but also let the user explore the map. My `didUpdateUserLocation` currently looks like this:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation {

    _currentLocation = userLocation;

    [self.mapView setRegion:MKCoordinateRegionMake(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(self.currentLocation.coordinate.latitude + 0.0015, self.currentLocation.coordinate.longitude), MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.01, 0.01)) animated:NO];

    [...]
}
```

Any ideas on what I should do to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you set the showsUserLocation property of your MKMapView as YES, the user location is automatically updated (cf Apple Docs).

You should remove the  "setRegion" line, because this line centers the view on the user location.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know a way to set the Zoom level of MKMapView without setting the region? I want it to be quite close to the user. And I only know my `_currentLocation` after `didUpdateUserLocation`.

Comment: I soved it by adding a BOOL ivar to only set `setRegion` once in `didUpdateUserLocation`.

Comment: If you want to set a zoom in a region other than the one centered on the user location, you can get the actual displayed region of the map with the region property.
You will have then the CLLocationCoordinate2D center and MKCoordinateSpan span.  By keeping the center and modifying the center, you change the zoomLevel.
Just set the new region with setRegion:animated: and you have your zoom :)

Answer (score 0):

I know the post is long gone, but I'd like to share what worked for me while searching for  answers to so many similar questions. Many of them didn't work at all. I wanted to move my location to one side while i emailed a screenshot of Annotations, otherwise I would have to zoom out so that the area under my pins only occupied exactly a quarter of the available area.

```
- (IBAction)beStill:(UIButton *)sender {
_mapView.showsUserLocation = NO;
}

- (IBAction)moveOn:(UIButton *)sender {
_mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
}
```

While i was still sorting it out I put two buttons on screen, but then refactored the UI so that whatever was the last control the user touched was also safe to infer whether he wanted it ON or OFF. Then i just slipped the statements into those respective methods, and deleted the beStill and moveOn buttons.

This is important because when you launch the app you first want the function ON, unless you're in the Atlantic off the west coast of Africa

That way i didn't have to do anything with setRegion